# How to expand list columns into rows in polars?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I am trying to **expand the list column data** into non list format in `Polars` but not able to do it.

**dataframe**

```
import polars as pl

pl_mtcars = pl.DataFrame({'model': ['Mazda RX4','Mazda RX4 Wag','Datsun 710','Hornet 4 Drive',
  'Hornet Sportabout','Valiant','Duster 360','Merc 240D','Merc 230','Merc 280'],
 'mpg': [21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2],
 'cyl': [6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6],
 'disp': [160.0,160.0,108.0,258.0,360.0,225.0,360.0,146.7,140.8,167.6],
 'hp': [110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123],
 'drat': [3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92],
 'wt': [2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 3.15, 3.44],
 'qsec': [16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.0, 22.9, 18.3],
 'vs': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 'am': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'gear': [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
 'carb': [4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4]}
 )
```

**creating list column dataset below**

```
pl_mtcars2 = .select([
    "model","mpg","cyl",
    pl.col("mpg").mean().over("cyl").alias("mean_mpg_by_cyl"),
    pl.col("mpg").over("cyl", mapping_strategy="join").alias("mpg_by_cyl") #.flatten() 
])

pl_mtcars2.head()
```

```
┌────────────────┬──────┬─────┬─────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ model          ┆ mpg  ┆ cyl ┆ mean_mpg_by_cyl ┆ mpg_by_cyl           │
│ ---            ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---             ┆ ---                  │
│ str            ┆ f64  ┆ i64 ┆ f64             ┆ list[f64]            │
╞════════════════╪══════╪═════╪═════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ Mazda RX4      ┆ 21.0 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ [21.0, 21.0, … 19.2] │
│ Mazda RX4 Wag  ┆ 21.0 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ [21.0, 21.0, … 19.2] │
│ Datsun 710     ┆ 22.8 ┆ 4   ┆ 23.333333       ┆ [22.8, 24.4, 22.8]   │
│ Hornet 4 Drive ┆ 21.4 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ [21.0, 21.0, … 19.2] │
│ …              ┆ …    ┆ …   ┆ …               ┆ …                    │
│ Duster 360     ┆ 14.3 ┆ 8   ┆ 16.5            ┆ [18.7, 14.3]         │
│ Merc 240D      ┆ 24.4 ┆ 4   ┆ 23.333333       ┆ [22.8, 24.4, 22.8]   │
│ Merc 230       ┆ 22.8 ┆ 4   ┆ 23.333333       ┆ [22.8, 24.4, 22.8]   │
│ Merc 280       ┆ 19.2 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ [21.0, 21.0, … 19.2] │
```

Getting **Error** when trying to **expand** `mpg_by_cyl` into rows instead of list

```
pl_mtcars2.select(pl.all(),
          pl.exclude('mpg_by_cyl'),
          pl.col('mpg_by_cyl').explode()).head(10)
```

Comment: if you just want to explode the `mpg_by_cyl` column, what about `pl_mtcars2.explode(['mpg_by_cyl'])`?

Comment: thanks @FObersteiner .. I didn't realize it is done this way. .. thanks again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can explode a column in a select context but you can't do that when other columns are present since then the dimension of the columns don't fit.

To explode a column and other columns expanding you have to use the explode method on a dataframe.

```
pl_mtcars2.explode("mpg_by_cyl")


shape: (38, 5)
┌───────────┬──────┬─────┬─────────────────┬────────────┐
│ model     ┆ mpg  ┆ cyl ┆ mean_mpg_by_cyl ┆ mpg_by_cyl │
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---             ┆ ---        │
│ str       ┆ f64  ┆ i64 ┆ f64             ┆ f64        │
╞═══════════╪══════╪═════╪═════════════════╪════════════╡
│ Mazda RX4 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 21.0       │
│ Mazda RX4 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 21.0       │
│ Mazda RX4 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 21.4       │
│ Mazda RX4 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 18.1       │
│ …         ┆ …    ┆ …   ┆ …               ┆ …          │
│ Merc 280  ┆ 19.2 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 21.0       │
│ Merc 280  ┆ 19.2 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 21.4       │
│ Merc 280  ┆ 19.2 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 18.1       │
│ Merc 280  ┆ 19.2 ┆ 6   ┆ 20.14           ┆ 19.2       │
└───────────┴──────┴─────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
```